# ¿Como limitar el numero de elementos ingresados de tipo int en un input?

Tags: html

Necesito la forma de saber como limitar los números ingresados, quisiera que el tope sea 16 y el mínimo 14 como lo puedo realizar?

```
<label for="number_card">Numeros de la tarjeta</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number_card" name="number_card" placeholder="Numeros de la tarjeta"  maxlength="16" required min="1" onkeypress="return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)">
```

Comment: min y max ?? Es lo más simple que puedes usar sin irte a otros lenguajes.

Comment: no importa usar java, lo que pasa es que no quiero poner max=9999999999999999 y min 1

Comment: Pues en ese caso, tendrías que validar el valor cuando se hace el cambio, o el submit, el que necesites tú, para que se controle de manera correcta. En el caso de min y max, funcionan durante el submit si no me equivoco.

Answer (score 1):

Sin modificar mucho tu código hay una solución bastante simple, usar patrones en el input, y controlar que no se metan caracteres no numéricos con el evento keypress (como ya haces).

```
<label for="number_card">Numeros de la tarjeta</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number_card" name="number_card" placeholder="Numeros de la tarjeta"  pattern="[0-9]{14,16}" title="14-16 digitos" onKeypress=" if (!(event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)) event.preventDefault()">
```

El patrón se comprueba al enviar el dato, aparece un aviso de que se debe introducir el texto de acuerdo al patrón.
Y en el keypress he invertido la lógica y si la tecla no es un dígito pues detiene el evento,y no sigue con el comportamiento por defecto con lo cual no agrega la letra o lo que se teclee.
Es la forma más sencilla que veo.
**EDITO**
Numeros de la tarjeta
= 48 && event.charCode

Ahora no acepta más de 16.

Comment: lo siento pero no me ha funcionado para lo que necesito

Comment: Si concretas lo que necesitas a lo mejor te puedo ayudar. La otra opción que veo es lo habitual: usar Javascript y validar una vez has pulsado el botón de submit.

Comment: mira, no tengo problema con validar, mi problema es cuando inserto mas de 16 caracteres y no bloquea el teclado, es lo que busco